# Adding Subscriber to Mailchimp Using Api 3.0 Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, post, fetch, mailchimp

I'm trying to add an subscriber to my Mailchimp list when the following meteor method runs.

I'm getting an error: Parameter "url" must be a string, not object.

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { check } from "meteor/check";
import { Logger } from "/server/api";
import request from "request";
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

const methods = {
  "myproject/addToMailchimp": (email) => {
    check(email, String);

    Logger.info(`contact person at ${email}`);

    const request2 = request("https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<LISTID>/members", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      mode: "no-cors",
      json: {
        email_address: email,
        status: "subscribed"
      },
      redirect: "follow",
      auth: {
        user: "<USERNAME>",
        pass: "<APIKEY>"
      }
    });


    fetch(request2).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
};

Meteor.methods(methods);
```

I would really appreciate any help on this. I've never used fetch or request before, so I reckon I'm not using these correctly.

Thanks!

Will

Comment: Show your work. Indicate to your audience what research you've done. Indicate what you found when you googled the error message, and why it wasn't helpful to you. Don't tell me what you've done; edit your question and tell everyone. Also, I don't see "url" or "URL" anywhere in your code. Where is the message coming from? Does it show up before any of your code runs, or does it happen while you're already running? What did you find out when you used your debugger to step through the problematic code? Again, don't tell me; edit your question.

Comment: Thanks. Now solved.